# linear upper bound on coefficients of taylor polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

let $f:\mathbb D\to \mathbb C\setminus [1,\infty)$ be holomorphic.
let $f(0)=0$
let $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$
show that $|a_n|\leq Cn$

attempt:
$|a_n|\leq \frac{1}{r^n} \sup_{|z|=r} |f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{r^n} \sup_{|z|=r} |F(z)|=\frac{4n^2}{(1-1/n)^{n-1}}$
where $F(z)=\frac{-4z}{(1-z)^2}$ and $r=1-\frac{1}{n}$
the first ineq is Cauchy's ineq.
the second ineq is due to this: $\sup_{|z|=r} |f(z)|\leq \sup_{|z|=r} |F(z)|$ for biholomorphic F
unfortunately, i'm not sure whether my argument is correct. even if it is, i can't get a linear bound..

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: @MartinR https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1633207 
the hints there might not helpful

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get anything better than a quadratic bound so far.

Comment: Personally I would move the n to the left-hand side and try to use the limit comparison test against the Harmonic series that is known to be divergent.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test